# Scheme satisfying certain condition is affine. Exercise 3.5 Qing Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $Y$ be a scheme such that the natural morphism
$$ Hom_{Schemes}(X,Y) \rightarrow Hom_{Rings}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X(X))$$
is bijective for all affine schemes $X$. Prove $Y$ is affine.

I have no idea how to prove this. Since $Y$ is scheme we can cover it by open affine subsets $Y=\bigcup_iU_i$, but I'm not sure how I can utilise the $U_i$. I know that

$$ Hom_{Schemes}(U_i,Y) \rightarrow Hom_{Rings}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_Y(U_i))$$
is bijective, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Hint (might not be enough but should help): Consider what happens when $X$ is the spectrum of $O_Y(Y)$ (as this scheme and more particularly the structure map $Y \rightarrow X$ is the “explicit condition” for $Y$ to be affine).

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks! The morphism corresponding to $id \in Hom_{Rings}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_Y(Y))= Hom_{Rings}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X(X))$ should give me the isomorphism, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely (there are things to check afterward, but that’s the start).

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that $Y \cong \text{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$, and by the $\text{Spec}$-$\Gamma$ adjunction we get a morphism of schemes $f:Y \to \text{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ (which I guess is called the 'unit' of the adjunction? I'm not sure what the terminology is for contravariant functors). To show $f$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to check its effect on functors of points (recall Yoneda): for all test schemes $T$ we have a commutative diagram (of sets) $$
   Y(T) := \text{Hom}_{\text{Sch}}(T,Y) \xrightarrow{f\circ-} (\text{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_Y(Y))(T):= \text{Hom}_{\text{Sch}}(T,\text{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_Y(Y))\\
\cong\,\downarrow \hspace{7cm} \downarrow\,\cong\\
\text{Hom}_{\text{Ring}}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_T(T)) \xrightarrow{=} \text{Hom}_{\text{Ring}}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_T(T))
$$ where the downwards left arrow is bijective by your hypothesis and the downwards right arrow is bijective by the mentioned adjunction, since $\text{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ is affine. This of course shows that $f\circ -$ is an isomorphism, regardless of $T$.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That’s a very nice way of putting it! Maybe you should specify that $T$ must be affine, which is still enough to conclude by “Yoneda”.

Comment: I was expecting that the statement could be proven through category-theory, however I haven't learned about the $Spec$-$\Gamma$ Adjunction yet. Is there a more ad-hoc proof?